# Prevent tableview cell recycle label value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a tableview with custom cell that contain 1 `label` and 1 `button`. The button is use for everytime I tap it, increase the number inside `label`, example if my `label` value is 0 then everytime I tap the button it is increase by 1

The problem is I have a lot of data, example I have 20 and everytime I set a value for the label when I scroll all the value is changed

this is my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let pos = cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UIButton

    pos.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testTableViewController.pos(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    pos.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}

func pos(sender: UIButton) {
    let position: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position)
    let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell

    let countNo = cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel

    var counter:Int = Int(countNo.text!)!
    counter = counter + 1
    countNo.text = String(counter)
}
```

please help me how to solve this problem. I have search a lot of web to find the answer, example like make `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` `nil` but in Swift 2 `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` never `nil` and a lot more with no one is work

I need some hint how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer.

Initialise one array having number of objects same as your tableview's number of row. Initially insert value "0" or blank string (if do not want to display any number in label initially) for each object.

ex,

```
var arrValues:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for _ in 1...numberOfrow

        {
            arrValues.addObject("0")
        }
```

Now in cellForRowAtIndexPath method , display text of label from this array

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("testCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        let pos = cell.viewWithTag(6) as! UIButton
        **let countNo = cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel
        countNo.text = String(arrValues.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))**

        pos.addTarget(self, action: #selector(testTableViewController.pos(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        pos.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
```

On button click method replace object at particular index with incremented number. See your updated method as below.

```
func pos(sender: UIButton) {
        let position: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(position)
        let cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell

        let countNo = cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UILabel

        var counter:Int = Int(countNo.text!)!
        counter = counter + 1
        countNo.text = String(counter)
        **arrValues.replaceObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row, withObject: String(counter))**
    }
```

So in cellForRowAtIndexPath , it will display updated number in label text

Comment: where do I have to put that `for _ in 1...numberOfrow { arrValues.addObject("0") }` ? If I put that in `viewDidLoad()`, I got error